# How to enable 2D acceleration (preferably using proprietary graphics driver) on 32bit pae kernel?

Tags: 10.10, xubuntu, ati, proprietary, pae

I recently switched from the generic 32bit kernel to the pae kernel thus enabling 10GiB instead of 3. After switching I noticed a different GUI behavior: When moving windows, I get ~3 redraws per second. With the non-pae kernel I use the proprietary amd/ati driver giving a nice 2D performance. Since I use this machine also as desktop, full 2D support is required. 3D would be nice. If possible, I'd use the proprietary driver.

Moving to 64bit is not an Option (I use a multiboot system and already have a working 64bit OS).

How to achieve full 2D acceleration with pae?

Comment: Reinstalled graphic driver?

Comment: @mount.cifs thx: reinstalled, now it works (only) with pae. I'm fine with that. As I'll mostly use the pae kernel a (possibly tricky) parallel installation is not needed.

Comment: "Moving to 64bit is not an Option (I use a multiboot system and already have a working 64bit OS)." <--- Can you explain further what you mean? Why can't you use more than one 64bit OS? And what 64bit OS do you use?

Comment: @Roland Taylor: The specific system is for development only. For the actual project I am forced to use some libs which are only provided as binary with headers built on a 32bit 10.10 ubuntu. Having the same environment reduces the chance to get into issues.

Comment: Yes, reinstall the graphics driver.  apt-get remove, then re-install with jockey.

Comment: have you solved this question or are you still looking for help? If you did find an answer please consider adding it below, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling graphics driver it only works for the kernel mode (32, 32pae) active when reinstalling. As I usually work with 32pae I'm fine with that.